# Flutter - MatrixGestureDetector is not working with flutter_swiper

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture, flutter-animation, flutter-swiper

I am using `flutter_swiper` to swipe images from a list a images. I want to use `MatrixGestureDetector` to move swiper containing images and perform zoom-in zoom-out to it. When i set the swiper layout to **Default** it works perfectly but when i change it to *Custom* or any other layout it stops working. Can anyone tell me what should be the problem???

Here is my code

```
Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
               

                        /// EYES
                        new Align(
                          child: MatrixGestureDetector(
                            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      notifier1.value =m;
                                    });


                            },
                            shouldRotate: false,
                            // shouldScale: true,
                            // shouldTranslate: false,
                            child: AnimatedBuilder(
                              animation: notifier1,
                              builder: (ctx, child) {
                                return Transform(
                                  transform: notifier1.value,
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.1),
                                        child: Tooltip(
                                          message: "Eyes Selected",
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: ew,
                                            height: eh,
                                            //color: Colors.purple,
                                            child: new SizedBox(
                                              child: Swiper(
                                                onTap: (index){
                                                  itemNo = 1;
                                                }
                                                ,
                                                itemBuilder:
                                                    (BuildContext context,
                                                    int index) {
                                                  return Image.asset(
                                                    eImage[index],
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                itemCount: eImage.length,
                                                itemWidth: 300,
                                                itemHeight: 600,
                                                //control: new SwiperControl(),
                                                layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
                                                
                                                customLayoutOption:
                                                CustomLayoutOption(
                                                    startIndex: -1,
                                                    stateCount: 3)
                                                    .addRotate([
                                                  0 / 180,
                                                  0.0,
                                                  0 / 180
                                                ]).addTranslate([
                                                  Offset(-400.0, 0.0),
                                                  Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                                  Offset(370, -40.0),
                                                ]),
                                              ),
                                              height: 200,
                                              width: 350,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. i was using custom layout just to give starting index dynamic but i later found that i can do it in default layout too. Swiper custom layout is buggy so i have raised the problem in git repository.

Solution:-

Use a variable for index:

`var pos=0` //any index u want

After that pass same index in swiper item builder and update it in runtime

```
                                            Swiper(
                                                onTap: (index){
                                                  itemNo = 1;
                                                }
                                                ,
                                                itemBuilder:
                                                    (BuildContext context,
                                                     pos) {
                                                  return Image.asset(
                                                    eImage[this.pos],
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                itemCount: eImage.length,
                                                itemWidth: 300,
                                                itemHeight: 600,
                                                  index: pos,
                                                  onIndexChanged: (int a)
                                                  {
                                                     pos=a; //updating new position 
                                                  },
                                              
                                                layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
                                              ),
```